# Android register/login doesnt work

Tags: android, networkonmainthread

Hello guys so i followed the androidhive for login/register android system and i added first name and lastname but for some reason when i click register my app crashes :(.Heres my code

DBConnect.php

```
 <?php

class DB_Connect {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'config.php';
        // connecting to mysql
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        // selecting database
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

        // return database handler
        return $con;
    }

    // Closing database connection
    public function close() {
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

ADDED : 
DBFunctions.php

```
<? db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->db->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}

/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO USERS(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
    // check for result
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $salt = $result['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $result;
        }
    } else {
        // user not found
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Check user is existed or not
 */
public function isUserExisted($email) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT email from USERS WHERE email = '$email'");
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        // user existed
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Encrypting password
 * @param password
 * returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashSSHA($password) {

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}

/**
 * Decrypting password
 * @param salt, password
 * returns hash string
 */
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

    return $hash;
}
```

}

?>

I would really appreciate help cus im completely stuck :S

P.S: insta shutdown after sucsses register posted logcat down

logcat :

```
    02-18 21:53:14.245: D/ProgressBar(18032): setProgress = 0
02-18 21:53:14.245: D/ProgressBar(18032): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
02-18 21:53:14.245: D/ProgressBar(18032): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
02-18 21:53:14.295: V/g f(18032):  f f
02-18 21:53:14.315: D/ProgressBar(18032): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
02-18 21:53:14.315: D/ProgressBar(18032): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
02-18 21:53:14.315: D/ProgressBar(18032): updateDrawableBounds: right = 64
02-18 21:53:14.315: D/ProgressBar(18032): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 64
02-18 21:53:14.665: V/err(18032): {"tag":"register","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"5303acb7aa41f9.88773766","user":{"name":"yr","email":"g f ","created_at":"2014-02-18 20:55:51","updated_at":null}}
02-18 21:53:14.815: D/AndroidRuntime(18032): Shutting down VM
02-18 21:53:14.815: W/dalvikvm(18032): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fbb930)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.babycare/com.example.babycare.DashboardActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1635)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1434)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3430)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3391)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at com.example.babycare.RegisterActivity.registerReport(RegisterActivity.java:87)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at com.example.babycare.RegisterTask.onPostExecute(RegisterTask.java:118)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at com.example.babycare.RegisterTask.onPostExecute(RegisterTask.java:1)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
02-18 21:53:14.820: E/AndroidRuntime(18032):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 21:53:56.860: I/Process(18032): Sending signal. PID: 18032 SIG: 9
02-18 21:53:57.435: D/dalvikvm(18161): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 114K, 52% free 3998K/8304K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
02-18 21:53:57.485: I/dalvikvm-heap(18161): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.782MB for 9216016-byte allocation
02-18 21:53:57.500: E/dalvikvm(18161): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=8388608, min=2097152, ut=568
02-18 21:53:57.500: D/dalvikvm(18161): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 25% free 12996K/17308K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
02-18 21:53:57.515: E/dalvikvm(18161): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=8388608, min=2097152, ut=368
02-18 21:53:57.515: D/dalvikvm(18161): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 25% free 12996K/17308K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 13ms
02-18 21:53:57.640: D/dalvikvm(18161): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9309K, 55% free 11331K/24956K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
02-18 21:53:57.685: D/libEGL(18161): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
02-18 21:53:57.685: D/libEGL(18161): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
02-18 21:53:57.690: D/libEGL(18161): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
02-18 21:53:57.690: E/(18161): Device driver API match
02-18 21:53:57.690: E/(18161): Device driver API version: 17
02-18 21:53:57.690: E/(18161): User space API version: 17 
02-18 21:53:57.690: E/(18161): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p1-01rel1 BUILD_DATE=Fri May 10 18:36:49 KST 2013 
02-18 21:53:57.715: D/OpenGLRenderer(18161): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: can you post the logcat error...?

Comment: Do you see `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in the logcat?

Comment: you should post exception

Comment: posted the logcat sorry for that :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later edit:

For the localhost problem: I assume you are using an emulator since you are using localhost. If you are not using an emulator and you are testing on a device, your device will have to be rooted in order to make it understand the localhost (you will have to be able to access the hosts file).

For the emulator:

1. If you are using eclipse as an IDE do the following: Open DDMS perspective (top right corner or Window->Open Perspective->DDMS). In the left panel choose your emulator. In the right panel choose the File Explorer tab and navigate to /system/etc. Select the hosts file and click on "Pull from device" (upper right corner, the disk symbol). This will save the hosts file to your file system. edit the host file and add this line: 10.0.2.2 localhost. Save the file and then go back to eclipse in the same DDMS perspective, select the hosts file and choose "Push a file to device" (upper right phone symbol) and select your hosts file.
2. For other IDEs (I only work with eclipse so I do not know their tools) or as an alternative to Eclipse you can use the ADB command line tools. A good tutorial is this: http://imagekarthik.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/how-to-modify-android-emulator-hosts-file/

Please post if there are other problems.

Ok, so the exception from logcat should read this way:

"NetworkOnMainThreadException" means that you are trying to get information through the network from the UI thread (where your activity resides). Android forbids this because it is usually a time/process/resources consuming operation and would most probably block the ui thread and make the user think the application is non-responsive.

The best way to deal with this is to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). A very good tutorial can be found here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

What you will have to do is change the UserFunction class to use the asyncTask for the register and login operations. Also, the onClick code from the register button from your main Activity should be refactored into the onPostExecute code of the AsyncTask for the register function in UserFunctions class.

Try to understand the concepts of asyncTask and android best practices for network operations. If you have further questions post them here.

Comment: now i cant enter my register form for some reason i posted logcat

Comment: Can you post what changes you have made to the RegisterActivity class? More importantly line 68 where you get the NullPointerException

Comment: posted and the added file aswell

Comment: btw im getting the crash when you start hte app and try to enter the register form then it crashes ;/

Comment: the exception is the same? (NullPointerException at line 68 in onCreate()) Because if that is the code for your RegisterActivity there is nothing at line 68. Please update the logcat as well with the error. Also, make sure the layout used (register) exists. There is no more need to get a reference  for the edittexts in the onCreate method, just for the button. Check to see if the button with that id exists in the layout.

Comment: ok i fixed most of the stuff but when i fill the register form and click register it keeps refusing my host i posted the logcat

Comment: The edit is in the post you voted as the answer. It was there from the time i wrote the previous comment. Please read it, try it and tell me if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Im using a device and im testing form a device its Samsung galaxy tab 3 8.0. So how im gonna make the app work for lets say other people if it cant run on a non rooted device O.o ?

Comment: Well you may run your application on a non-rooted device, but you cannot test it with localhost on a non-rooted device. I presume that the final users of the application will not register on your home/work computer. Even so, if your home/work computer will be the host for the web service where the users will register you will have a public IP that they will access to register and they will be able to access that from any device. To test your application before making it public use an emulator: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Comment: ok i tested on emulator worked grate.But when i puted it up on a web server and made it use that it began crashes(when i use it on device) and also for some reason it still continues to look for localhost ...

Comment: Make sure you change the URL everywhere in your code where you previously used localhost (usually i have a constants class where i define API_URL and use that API_URL everywhere in my app so i can change it easily). Also make sure that the url you are trying to connect is accessible outside of the android app (try to access the url in a browser, in a test code (php cURL or java HTTPConnection) or by any other possible means to make sure the link is accessible). If problem persists post the logcat to see what errors are thrown.

Comment: Ok heres what happened i changed everywhere it seemt i had one missed spot.But here came another problem wiht one of my php files i posted its logcat and the php file itself no clue why its making a problem here.I also want to thank you for the help so far :)

Comment: The PHP file you posted is a little "foggy" (i guess it is just a part of a class or something). As the JAVA error says, there is an error on line 1 of your DBFunctions.php file and i guess that db = new DB_Connect(); should instead be **$db=new DB_Connect()**. Also next line I think it should be **$db->connect** as I do not see any object on which to call $this->db. Anyway, test your register code separately from  the android app (use curl to make test post requests. An example here: http://devzone.co.in/post-data-using-curl-in-php-a-simple-example/).

Comment: Its Part of my DBConnect.php which i posted.It Works outisde the app.

Comment: oh i start to get Unexpected T_NEW from the logcat on that first line

Comment: please test the php code separately and then test it with android. it is difficult to debug this kind of architecture and it is so much simpler to test them separately. Test the PHP code until you get the desired results and then test the 2 applications working together.

Comment: OK i did some stuff and it fixed the stuff and from the logcat it seems it makes the app sucsessfuly but then it directkly shut down i posted hte logcat not even a single clue why it happens.

Comment: FINALLY it worked all fixed there was tons of errors in the PHP files  i had to fix aswell i forgot to include the sadboardactivity in the manifest and its now ok it logs/ register and encrypt all perfectly ty for the help and your whole day :)

Answer (score 1):

As i suspected you have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. You cannot do network related operation on the ui thread.

You should use a `Thread` or a `Asynctask` for this purpose.

In `UserFunctions` you have

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
```

In JSONparser you have

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 
// not possible on the ui thread
```

Move the http request to `Asynctask` or `Thread`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Clear you logcat first:

$ adb logcat -c

Then run it again:

$ adb logcat

Now,  launch your application

When the application crashes, copy the logcat output and paste it here.

Comment: i have posted the logcat :)

Comment: This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. You need to run your code in AsyncTask:
class HTTPRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Result> {
    protected Result doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {       
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            return null;
        }
    }
   protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        // TODO: do something with the feed
    }
}
To execute the task:
new HttpRequestTask().execute(url);

Answer (score 0):

You should do the network related tasks in the background thread using the doinbackground() of asyncTask